# I cannot choose the Firebase Directory in command line

Tags: html, css, firebase, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I want to host a website via Firebase hosting. When i run `firebase init` on cmd i get this:

```
First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,but for now we'll just set up a default project.
i  .firebaserc already has a default project, using my_project.
```

How can i change my project? Since I've deleted the *default* project that firebase mentioned, when i run `firebase deploy` i got this error:

```
Error: Failed to get Firebase project my_project. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.
```

Can anyone show me the way out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is very simple. All you have to do is go into your `.firebaserc` and change the `defualt` to the name of your project. You can probably also just delete `.firebaserc` and rerun `firebase init`.